# NPM - Copy files with CPX in postinstall script

Tags: npm, post-install

I published a module - `Module A`. I want to set this module to  automatically copy a folder to the root directory AFTER installation. I created below `index.js` file

```
//Module A - index.js`

var cpx = require('cpx');
cpx.copy('node_modules/path/to/module-a/folder/to/copy/*.*', 'dest/');

//Module A - package.json under the scripts section

"postinstall": node ./node_modules/module-a
```

I created a new project and installed `Module A`. The `postinstall` script was executed but the files were NOT copied to the destination. but if I ran the command `node ./node_modules/module-a` manually again, it worked.

1. Just wondering why the script was not working when running is postinstall stage.
2. or there is a better way to do this copy action?

Answer (score 1):

FYI, as of 2020, it appears that the CPX project is abandoned (last release was 3 years ago, authors won't fix reported vulnerabilities). [cpx-fixed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cpx-fixed) is a good alternative.

Comment: The alternative is abandoned/unmaintained too now